# Having trouble setting different input widths while using type=number for mobile

Tags: css, forms, mobile

I have 2 type="number" inputs (for mobile) that I'm trying to set a different width for each.

`.someclass input{ width:50px; }` does not work

`#someid input{ width:50px; }` doesnt work either

The only way i've found to alter an input with type="number" is by doing

`input[type="number"]{ width:50px; }`

But again...

`.someclass input[type="number"]{ width:50px; }` does not work

`#someid input[type="number"]{ width:50px; }` doesn't work either

Is it possible to set the width of 2 different inputs with type="number"?

Comment: It is possible doing <style>input[type="number"]{width50px;}</style> right before each input which is what im doing now... but that looks ugly and would like it in a css file.

Comment: Have you tried using `!important`? This is a bad practice, but if `.someclass input[type="number"]{ width:50px !important; }` works, then your style is being overridden elsewhere. A JSFiddle or an example of your code would be helpful as well.

Comment: !important does not work, my stylesheet is pretty clean and I know for a fact that I'm not over writing classes or ids. I'd show you the 2 pages explore & construct... but it's inside a game that I haven't released yet. Create 2 <input type="number"> and try to set a different width for both. I've tried, and searched and searched but cannot find a solution.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the class/ID correctly? If `!important` doesn't work either it sounds like `.someclass` or `#someid` are misspelled (or maybe missing in the HTML?). Sorry, without code it's everything I can think of.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QENqp/ doesn't work. This is my first question, and I haven't had to ask for help in my 10 years of building games, but this is my first mobile compatible type game so I'd like to use type=number so the proper numpad shows up.

Comment: In other words I'm a pretty smart cookie.. so give it a try. I'm not lying that it doesn't work. Unless there is another way to write it, I've tried for 2 nights, with multiple searches and tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the code! Now I see the problem. :)

`.first input[type="number"]` in CSS means "all `input` elements with type `number` that are **inside** an element with class `first`".

It would apply to a structure like:

```
<div class="first">
    <input type="number">
</div>
```

In your case, where the inputs are the ones that have classes, you could either use `x-type-element.YClass` (which means all `x-type` elements that **have** class `YClass`) or use just the class/ID, like in [these examples](http://jsfiddle.net/QENqp/1/). Both are good solutions, although the first one can give you incompatibility issues with old browsers (i.e. Internet Explorer).

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, this works! The simplest things eh? I'd upvote you but I guess i need 15 reputation points first =/

Comment: I find it wierd how .first input{ } does work.. but not with a type=number =/ Thank you again.

Comment: You are very welcome! Yes, the simplest things, indeed, we are all there very very often. xD I think you can accept the answer though (the checked symbol under the votes count), and that'll give you a little more reputation as well. :)